# Argparse: set the name of a choice arg in the command 'help'

Tags: python, argparse

In argparse, a choice argument can be created by using code like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", type=str,
                    help="The action to do. Eligible values:\ninstall, remove, version", choices=['install', 'remove', 'version'])
```

When `parser` is an instance of `argparse.ArgumentParser()`

However, when displaying the help, instead of the arg being specified as its name, it is specified as `{install,remove,version}`, the whole output being

```
positional arguments:
  {install,remove,version}
                        The action to do. Eligible values: install, remove,
                        version

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

How can i get his to display the name of the arg, so the output is more like

```
positional arguments:
  action                The action to do. Eligible values: install, remove,
                        version

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `metavar` parameter to `add_argument` is what you're looking for:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "action",
    type=str,
    help="The action to do. Eligible values:\ninstall, remove, version",
    choices=['install', 'remove', 'version'],
    metavar="action",
)
```

Calling `parser.print_help()` yields:

```
usage: [-h] action

positional arguments:
  action      The action to do. Eligible values: install, remove, version

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify [metavar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#metavar)

> When ArgumentParser generates help messages, it needs some way to refer to each expected argument. By default, [...] An alternative name can be specified with metavar:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("action", type=str, metavar='action',
                    help="The action to do. Eligible values:\ninstall, remove, version", choices=['install', 'remove', 'version'])
```